# "Product Recommendations"

Tags: discussion

[Single speed dirt jump specific frame for general riding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/39106/single-speed-dirt-jump-specific-frame-for-general-riding/39112#39112)

This question was put on hold.  It's a fairly specific question that is definitely answerable.  The OP may have over committed a bit by including specific bike examples, but it is still quite the valid question.  If someone posted a "I want to ride criteriums, but occasionally downhill race, would a carbon endurance road bike work well for me for both?"  The question would be easily answered.  If we can't make recommendations for what styles of frames/bikes are appropriate to riding conditions unbiased by the riding styles being asked about, perhaps we need to look back at many other questions for closure as well.

Comment: To add confusion there is also a [product-rec](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-rec) and [purchasing](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tags/product-rec/synonyms) tags.  As a community we are not particularly consistent in our point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way to look at product recommendations would be to avoid specific brand/model recs, rather than.banning all types of broad category advice.

In addition, when an OP asks a question which has a brand/model request, it is up to how we answer as much as their question whether it becomes an advert or not.

I do think we are often too quick to close questions before they have time to be explored properly.

I know that a question can be reopened, but closing it too quickly is a shock to many new posters and might be a deterrent to them becoming a long term part of our community.

Comment: *[W]e are often too quick to close questions* - I completely agree. I think our esteemed moderators use their power to close just a *little* too often, or too quickly. It must be a fine line that you try to tread. But it's related to to the next issue: it would be helpful if more of the 60 users with 3k rep were involved with the review queues. The close queue is currently showing the last six active users as andy256, Criggie, Móż, Gary.Ray♦, zenbike♦, jimirings♦.